Which reward for completing "The Blessings of Nature" is the better one?
I am trying to find out what the rewards are for completing the quest "The Blessings of Nature".
Since there happen to be two methods for completing the quest, it is fair to assume that there will be a difference in the rewards granted in regards to which way you choose to complete it.
Is the sap or is the sapling the better option for getting better quest completion rewards?

The sap or the sapling have no other uses beyond aiding the Gildergreen.
Neither quest path is better, except for your idea of what constitutes moral goodness (within the confines of a game).
To get the sap to save Gildergreen, the tree in Whiterun, you need to cut the Eldergleam, a legendary tree. This tree will be protected by Spriggans. Cutting the tree will awaken these spirit guardians, and force them to try to kill you and the peaceful pilgrims in the Eldergleam Sanctuary.
Maurice Jondrelle, one of the pilgrims who had visited Whiterun to see the Gildergreen and saw its pitiful state, will be there to offer an alternative: instead of damaging this ancient tree he will pray to Kynareth for an alternative solution. This will result in a sapling visibly growing from the ground, which can be taken to Whiterun to replace the withering Gildergreen.
In the words of the UESP:

You can either choose to hear [Maurice] out, which will result in a peaceful solution – or you can choose to ignore him and use Nettlebane to extract the sap, and awaken the wrath of Kynareth.

Now, this quest always bothered me: I believe that temporarily slightly damaging a tree to retrieve sap to aid another dying tree is a perfectly ethically responsible action to make - the Eldergleam will easily heal, and the Gildergreen will get to live again. But the game developers don't seem to see it this way, and portray this as the evil path, as those Spriggans will just start killing everyone if they get the chance. If Maurice is present, he will also attack you.
Sure, letting someone peacefully pray for a sapling is the more pacifist alternative, but that means cutting down the Gildergreen to make way for the sapling; to uproot a tree that is apparently still alive. So roleplaying this quest properly really depends on your moral compass or lack thereof.
Ultimately the choice, stripped of morality, is: do you want to fight four Spriggans and their Matriarch, or not? In my experience it is always a tough fight.
No matter what course of action you take, you will get Master Training in Restoration from Danica, so the different rewards are barely and only temporarily different.
